# Azure Consumption API Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api, azure-billing-api, azure-cost-calculation

This is a segment of Azure consumption API result for my azure account. I am stuck in the understanding of **"usageQuantity": 0.000000100582838** parameter(whether it's a CPU ultilization or something else). Is there a brief explanation of this parameter ? how can I verify its value from my azure account?

```
 { 
    "id": "/subscriptions/*****/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202302/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/****",
      "name": "****",
            "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
            "tags": null,
            "properties": {
                "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202302",
                "usageStart": "2023-02-02T00:00:00.0000000Z",
                "usageEnd": "2023-02-02T23:59:59.0000000Z",
                "instanceId": "/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/powerbi_dashboard/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sample-instance",
                "instanceName": "sample-instance",
                "instanceLocation": "Asia",
                "meterId": "941a7a91-f0b4-4c70-be0f-d87ea6ff09ee",
                "usageQuantity": 0.000000100582838,
                "pretaxCost": 0.000000631774907,
                "currency": "INR",
                "isEstimated": false,
                "subscriptionGuid": "****",
                "subscriptionName": "Basic Subscription",
                "product": "",
                "consumedService": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "partNumber": "",
                "resourceGuid": "****",
                "offerId": "MS-AZR-0044P",
                "chargesBilledSeparately": false,
                "meterDetails": null
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the information about the meter in use("941a7a91-f0b4-4c70-be0f-d87ea6ff09ee") : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/list-billing-meters/list-billing-meters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-pricesheet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/#getting-list-of-billing-periods

Answer (score 0):

The `usageQuantity` property will be different per resource type. I can see you are using a Virtual Machine.

Usage for a VM is based on the total compute hours for that size VM.

> we bill for each minute the VM ran for a given hour

> For Compute Hour usage, there is a meter for each VM Size + OS (Windows, Non-Windows) + Region.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/vm-usage

You can see your start and end times are only a minute hence the value is extremely low.

Comment: If you look closely usage for VM is for one day and not for one minute. Is there any formula by which I can compare my value with virtual machine metric in Azure portal?

Comment: Good point on the times. You can use the meterId and further API calls to get the cost